# Issue faced during the implementation of the regex expression in HTML form

Tags: regex, validation, regex-negation

**Scenario:**

I have tested the following regex expression in https://www.regextester.com/ And it performs the validation as required. That means it doesn't allow the expression containing '@' character.

**Issue Faced:**

But, when I implement the same regex expression for form validation in HTML then it fails to validate. That means it also allows the expressions containing '@' character, which is not the required outcome.

**Here is the regex expression:**

```
 ^[a-z0-9]+\.([a-z0-9])+(?!@)+(?!outlook.com)+(?!gmail.com)+$
```

**Implementation in the HTML Form as:**

```
<td>
<input type="text" name="exchange_usertoadd" required="required"
pattern="^[a-z0-9]+\.([a-z0-9])+(?!@)+(?!outlook.com.np)+(?!gmail.com)+$" 
placeholder="Enter Exchange Username" value="" size="30">
</td>
```

**Required Outcome:**

**1. The above regex expression should allow the following expressions:**

a. john.mayor

b. michael.clarke

c. jitendra123.gurung

and so on.

**2. But it shouldn't allow the following expressions:**

a. john.mayor@gmail.com

b. jitendra.gurung@

c. sarad@

d. michael.clarke@outlook.com

and so on.

**What correction do I need in the implementation of the regex expression that I have tried above?**

*Suggestions are highly appreciated.*

Comment: On regex101.com, I get a bunch of "the preceding token is not quantifiable" https://regex101.com/r/1cNe5p/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like:

```
/^([a-z0-9]*([.])*([a-z0-9]))+(?!outlook.com.np)(?!gmail.com)/mg
```

Its in JS pattern, please change it for your input field

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wXIMo7/13)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am reading your requirements too loosely, but what about using `^[^@]+$` for your regular expression? It matches all of your given test cases.

Answer (score 0):

*I modified the expression and it meets the requirements that I need for the validation.*

**This is the correct working expression which meets my requirement:**

```
^([a-z0-9]*([.])*([a-z0-9]))+(?!@)(?!outlook.com.np)(?!gmail.com)+$
```